# How to sign Amazon S3 request without providing AWS Credentials?

Tags: security, amazon-s3

We have a Java product which may put and get data from Amazon S3. We already successfully implemented a class responsible of that by using the Amazon SDK for Java.

But, as far as I know, to interact with Amazon S3 through the library, you have to instantiate an `AmazonS3Client`object by providing an access key and a secret key.

Even if this technique can be relatively safe by using Amazon IAM and restrict access of the keys to the specific bucket of S3 you want to pull and put data, it is still a security hole in a sense that someone could decompile your application to extract the keys and use them to access your bucket's data.

Is there a safer way to do that ? Can we avoid to embed the AWS credentials in the application ? Can we make a REST call to our server to sign the requests (and keep the keys secret) ?

Comment: The latest SDK supports InstanceProfile credentials when your application is deployed on EC2; this prevents having to embed credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Amazon Secure Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html) ([JavaDoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/package-summary.html)) as well as the [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490) to see if these help to resolve your issue.